# PHP.INI not working?

Tags: php, cpanel

Okay my question is a bit confusing but for a few days, I have been noticing some unusual changes in my cPanel account.

I tried installing Joomla3.
And it gave me a precheck error, I fixed it by creating a php.ini file to fix the errors.
It worked.

But when it came to putting the php.ini file in the root directory so that I could fix max post size to 32mb. It never allowed more than 2mb, which was the default value on my shared hosting.

Im not sure why, but this has been happening for quite a while now.
Any suggestions on why his would be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is an old question of mine, I now know that you can not just change max_upload or max_post just by putting in a custom php.ini

What you need to do is to restart apache in order to make this work :)

Hope this helps anyone who has this issue :)